# Twig set a value from a string and variable

Tags: twig

```
{% set url = '/f/' . topic.name . '/' %}
```

I have some problems getting this to work. Anyone knows how to do this correctly?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Concatenation is done with a `~`:

```
{% set url = '/f/' ~ topic.name ~ '/' %}
```